# get single item from ngrx/store

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, store, ngrx

I've written the following reducer to store the state items in my Angular 2 app.  The Items are price offers for Financial Instruments (e.g. stocks/currencies).

My Reducer Implementation is as follows:

```
export const offersStore = (state = new Array<Offer>(), action:Action) => {
switch(action.type){

    case "Insert":
        return [
            ...state, action.payload
        ];
    case "Update":
            return state.map(offer => {
                    if(offer.Instrument === action.payload.Instrument)
                    {
                        return Object.assign({}, action.payload);
                    }
                    else return offer;
            });
    case "Delete":
        return state.filter(offer => offer.Instrument !== action.payload )
    default:
        return state;
    }
```

}

I managed to get Inserts, Updates and Deletes working - although it wasn't easy.  I find Redux to be something of a paradigm shift away from how I've been coding for years.

I've got an Instrument Component/Page on my App - which shows all available information for one specific Instrument, indicated by InstrumentId e.g. "EUR/USD" (stored in the payload.Instrument property).

My problem is, I'm not sure how to efficiently search for a specific instrument and grab it out of the store.  Not only this, but I also want the instrument I fetch to be updated if the Instrument in the store is updated as they are frequently via websocket push from the server.  So I really need to search the store for a specific instrument, and return it as an Observable, that will continue to update the View Component based on new data that gets pushed to the store.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I encounter many of the same questions when I first started working with redux/ngrxStore.  I took heavy inspiration from the ngrx example app. https://github.com/ngrx/example-app   If you look at the way they compose their state and retrieve values it can help.  With Redux it is encouraged for you to normalize your states similar to database tables.  My second hurdle was learning how to effectively use observables and rxjs.  When done right you can really simplify your code and make it very readable (assuming you understand the rxjs operators) and your app very fast and testable.

Comment: These react/redux examples ported over to use ngrx/store might help some too.
https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-examples

Comment: They essentially build indexes against the state. 
const newBookEntities = newBooks.reduce((entities: { [id: string]: Book }, book: Book) => {
        return Object.assign(entities, {
          [book.id]: book
        });
      }, {});

Comment: And then use that id to get directly to the object.  state$
    .select(s => s.entities[id]);

Comment: Did this help at all?

Comment: HAHA no not really I am still totally lost with all this.  But I'm digging through the links you provided trying to figure it out.  There's plenty of videos and tutorials online about NgRx but none that go into anything more complex than one reducer.  All I can do is dig through code and try to work out what is happening - but its not exactly clear.  Thanks for taking the time to write!

Comment: No worries.  Trust me.  It took a while to understand.  I had to beef up on my ES6 and javascript too.  This isn't a easy subject but if you want the extra performance it is definitely worth it.

Comment: You might find some good info here: https://gist.github.com/btroncone/a6e4347326749f938510, https://egghead.io/lessons/angular-2-ngrx-store-in-10-minutes

Answer (score 14):

For every action that is called on a reducer, the new state is returned.

From the example code in the question, state is just a list of instruments.
There's no index, so the only way to check if an instrument is in the list is to search the whole list.

But what if your state was a dictionary? Furthermore, what if you kept a list of indexes seperate to the dictionary?

your state type is this:

```
export interface OfferState {
  ids: string[];
  entities: { [id: string]: IOffer };
};
```

Any time an action is executed, the new state is returned. It is an important concept in Redux, because state can never be mutated directly.  You're actually best strictly enforcing this when you compose your reducer: (say you've got you "offers reducer" and another reducer,  you combine them to one with compose:

```
> export default compose(storeFreeze, combineReducers) ({   oether:
> otherReducer,   offers: offersReducer });
```

Its easy to do things wrong in Redux - but using storeFreeze will throw up an error if you try to mutate the state directly.  The point is that actions change state, and make a new state. They don't change the existing state - it lets us undo/redo... etc.

Using your example above I would use this as my Offer's reducer:

```
export interface OfferState {
  ids: string[];
  entities: { [id: string]: IOffer };
};

export default function(state = initialState, action: Action): OfferState {
    switch(action.type){
        case OfferActions.INSERT:
        const offer : IOffer = action.payload;
        return {
            ids: [ ...state.ids, action.payload.Instrument ],
            entities: Object.assign({}, state.entities, { [action.payload.Instrument]: action.payload})
        };
        case OfferActions.UPDATE:
            return {
                ids: [...state.ids],
                entities: Object.assign({}, state.entities,  { [action.payload.Instrument]: action.payload})
            }

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

note that changes are made to a temporary state via object.assign (deep copy) and then the new state is returned.

The other answer to the question was a bit confusing. It went into the detail of how to combine different reducers, but it didn't make much sense to me.

in your reducers/index.ts you should have a type:

```
export interface AppState {
  otherReducer: OtherReducer;
  offers: fromOffersReducer.OfferState;
}
```

inside this index.ts, you should have functions that get the reducers:

```
export function getOfferState() {
  return (state$: Observable<AppState>) => state$
    .select(s => s.offers);
}

export function getOtherReducer() {
  return (state$ : Observable<AppState>) => state$
    .select(s => s.otherReducer)
}
```

inside our offerReducer and our otherReducer, we define functions that can query the data we need. These are anonymous functions, that are not linked to anything at present, but we will link them later (to the getReducerFunctions).

examples of these functions:

```
export function getOfferEntities() {
  return (state$: Observable<OfferState>) => state$
    .select(s => s.entities);
};

export function getOffer(id: string) {
  return (state$: Observable<OfferState>) => state$
    .select(s => s.entities[id]);
}
```

this does nothing. unless we apply it to some useful data (e.g. the offersRedeucer) that we made ealier, and we combine the two like this:

```
import offersReducer, * as fromOffersReducer from './OffersReducer';

 export function getOfferEntities() {
   return compose(fromOffersReducer.getOfferEntities(), getOfferState());
 }

  export function getOffer(instrument:string) {
   return compose(fromOffersReducer.getOffer(instrument), getOfferState());
 }
```

Comment: I went to great depths to answer this question as best I could.  I feel more than a bit slighted and this has discourage my participation in this forum unfortunately.  I respect there is a opinion aspect here but as much as I would like to be helpful and explaining things helps me understand the subject better this hasn't been a positive experience.

Comment: More detailed?  Maybe he was able to hone in on the part you weren't understanding better but he reiterated a lot of what I had already written.

Comment: This doesn't matter ultimately.  I'm glad you got the answer you sought.  I don't really get what he told you that I didn't but like I said there is a opinion aspect to marking a answer and I'll respect that.

Comment: but you answered your own question

Comment: Nope, I definitely didn't.  There was a bounty on this question, I cannot award the answer to myself....  I have no idea why I'm listed as answering it.

Comment: All of my questions and answers for the last 6 months have VANISHED too.  I'm fricking devastated.

Comment: I know a developer who works at StackExchange.  I've DM'd him on twitter.  I don't really care about being assigned my own answer but I want all my Questions and Answers back from this year.

Answer (score 8):

Okay I'll give it a shot at explaining a way to set this up and hopefully do it in a way you and others can understand.

So if you are storing a array of objects and need to get access to a row by a certain id or key then the way the ngrx example app shows you can do this is to create a object containing your object which will use (in the case of their book app) the book's id as the property key.  You can set any string as a property name.  So say you have your state with a property called "entities" whose value is a blank object.  You can then take your array and create properties on the "entities" Object.

```
export interface BooksState {
  entities: { [id: string]: Book };
};
```

Lets start with just one row in the array of book objects.  To add this row to the "entities" object you do it like this.

```
 reducerState.entities[book.id] = book;
```

The above will make the book's id a property on the "entities" object.
If you were to inspect it in the console or debug tools it might look something like this after its creation.

```
 reducerState.entities.15: { id: 15, name: "To Kill a Mockingbird" }
```

The ngrx example app operates on the full array to add it to the state using the reduce operator on the javascript array.

```
   const newBookEntities 
              = newBooks.reduce(
                  (entities: { [id: string]: Book }, book: Book) => 
                           { 
                              return Object.assign(entities, { [book.id]: book }); 
                           }, {});
```

And then create special functions to get parts of this state that can be composed together later to get the specific rows you need

```
export function getBooksState() {
  return (state$: Observable<AppState>) => state$
    .select(s => s.books);
}


export function getBookEntities() {
  return (state$: Observable<BooksState>) => state$
   .select(s => s.entities);
};
export function getBooks(bookIds: string[]) {
  return (state$: Observable<BooksState>) => state$
              .let(getBookEntities())
              .map(entities => bookIds.map(id => entities[id]));
   }
```

And they compose these in the index.ts barrel in the example

```
import { compose } from '@ngrx/core/compose';


export function getBooks(bookIds: string[]) {
   return compose(fromBooks.getBooks(bookIds), getBooksState());
}
```

This function will chain the calls together going from right to left.  First calling getBooksState to get the reducer state and then calling fromBooks.getBooks and passing in the bookid's you want and the state from the previous "getBooksState" and allowing you to do the mapping to the selected states you need.

In your component you can import this function and use it to get just the books you want.

```
myBooks$: Observable<Books>  =  this.store.let(getBooks(bookIds)));
```

This returned observable is updated every time the store is updated.

**Added:** So the operator "let" on the store object passes in the current observable holding the store's state object to the function that is returned by the "getBooks" function.

Lets look closer at that.

```
export function getBooks(bookIds: string[]) {
   return compose(fromBooks.getBooks(bookIds), getBooksState());
}
```

Two functions are passed into the compose function here -- fromBooks.getBooks(bookIds) and getBooksState().  The compose function allows a value to be passed into the first function on the right and have that functions results passed into the function on the left and so on and so on.  So in this case we are going to take the results of the function returned by "getBooksState" and pass it into the function returned by the function "fromBooks.getBooks(bookIds)" and then ultimately return that result.

These two functions take in a Observable.  In the case of the function returned by getBooksState() it takes in as a parameter the store state observable object from which it will map/select (map and select are aliases for each other)  to the slice of the store we care about and return the new mapped observable.  That mapped observable will be passed into the function returned from the fromBooks.getBooks(bookIds) function.  This function expects the state slice observable.  This function does the new mapping by pulling out only the entities we care about.  This new observable is what is ultimately returned by the "store.let" call.

If you need more clarification then please ask questions and I'll do my best to clarify.

https://github.com/ngrx/example-app

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  Can you explain this syntax: entities: { [id: string]: Book };  I'm not sure what that is expressing.  What's the JS equivalent?

Comment: That is a type declaration for TypeScript.  It simply says the entities object should have property names made of a string with values that are book objects or meet the book object interface.  There isn't a equivalence in JavaScript and when compiled in TypeScript this won't carry down to the JavaScript.  It is only there for linting the TypeScript code to insure the proper types are passed in (in this case into a function).

Comment: OK I'm getting there!!!  Couple of questions.  The what does let do in this.store.let(getBooks())?  And the Special functions for getting the state return observables.  How can I get the state now rather than waiting for a  change to publish to the Observable?

Comment: The store object is at it's essence a BehaviorSubject ( its part of RXJS) so all you have to do is subscribe to it to get the current value.  The "let" on store is equivalent to the "let" operator for rxjs.
https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/let.md

The "let" operator allows you to work on the original observable. The main store is essentially just a plain javascript object that is wrapped in a observable.  So in this case it is passing a reference to the store's observable to the function returned by the function getBooks.

Comment: If you look at getBooks it is returning a function that takes a state$ Observable as a parameter.  
export function getBooks(bookIds: string[]) {
  return (state$: Observable<BooksState>) => state$
    .let(getBookEntities())
    .map(entities => bookIds.map(id => entities[id]));
}

Comment: A lot of this is covered in this github Gist.  https://gist.github.com/btroncone/a6e4347326749f938510 
I highly suggest going through it slowly and understanding each part.  I also recommend spending some time reviewing the rxjs docs and the individual documentation on the operators.

Comment: I've added a further explanation to bottom of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the further explaination.  I am getting close!  I have things going into the store using the new stateful format.  but I can't seem to get anything out.  Can you give me an example of a component that needs to get a single book from the store?

Comment: I'm disinclined to write any more due to the fact I feel you've yet to learn the basics of Redux and rxjs.  I've provided links to several examples.  All of which show you how to do what you are asking.  I think we've reached a wall as to what stack overflow questions are meant to answer.  They aren't meant to be complete tutorials.

Comment: Never mind - it was a stupid error on my part. I had another type named AppState exported elsewhere in my solution and I imported the wrong one into the component.  And thank you - I did read the examples.

Comment: For this.store.let(getBooks(bookIds))) 'This returned observable is updated every time the store is updated.'. I could achieve this in my store. But, is it possible to create an observable that is updated for a particular entity (by its id)?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly then you might want to try the distinctUntilChanged rxjs operator.
https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/distinctuntilchanged.md