# Extracting specific data from ngrx/store

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

So I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38957510/get-single-item-from-ngrx-store) post several times, but the defined setup and examples now differ from the methods shown in the [store example app](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app).

I have written my store code, based heavily off of the example app, so if we continue to use the example app for reference in this post:

Book Reducer:

```
export interface State {
  ids: string[];
  entities: { [id: string]: Book };
  selectedBookId: string | null;
};

const initialState: State = {
  ids: [],
  entities: {},
  selectedBookId: null,
};

export function reducer(state = initialState, action: book.Actions | collection.Actions): State {
  switch (action.type) {
    case book.ActionTypes.SEARCH_COMPLETE:
    case collection.ActionTypes.LOAD_SUCCESS: {
      const books = action.payload;
      const newBooks = books.filter(book => !state.entities[book.id]);

      const newBookIds = newBooks.map(book => book.id);
      const newBookEntities = newBooks.reduce((entities: { [id: string]: Book }, book: Book) => {
        return Object.assign(entities, {
          [book.id]: book
        });
      }, {});

      return {
        ids: [ ...state.ids, ...newBookIds ],
        entities: Object.assign({}, state.entities, newBookEntities),
        selectedBookId: state.selectedBookId
      };
    }

export const getEntities = (state: State) => state.entities;
export const getIds = (state: State) => state.ids;
```

Reducers index.ts (shortened but keeping relevant information):

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';
import { compose } from '@ngrx/core/compose';
import { storeFreeze } from 'ngrx-store-freeze';
import { combineReducers } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as fromBooks from './books';


export interface State {
  books: fromBooks.State;
}

const reducers = {
  books: fromBooks.reducer,
};

const productionReducer: ActionReducer<State> = combineReducers(reducers);
export function reducer(state: any, action: any) {
    return productionReducer(state, action);

}

export const getBooksState = (state: State) => state.books;
export const getBookEntities = createSelector(getBooksState, fromBooks.getEntities);
export const getBookIds = createSelector(getBooksState, fromBooks.getIds);
```

Now what I can't quite grasp is how the "query's" are built, what I want to be able to do is pass an ID say "456" to a function that will look inside State from the book with id "456". Return this data into an observable of Book so I can then use it inside my template/component whatever.

I have looked at the example code for hours and just when I think I have grasped it, I can't work out what I have done wrong. If anyone is able to explain how to build a selector that takes custom arguments.

I have used the exact code from the example app in the hope that if an answer is found it would be of help to future readers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you are using the redux pattern you have to do all by Actions.

**First** you need to store the selected ID in your Store in this case is the "selectedBookId" attribute as a new Action like SELECTED_BOOK

**Second** to get the selected book you will need to create a selector that combine the selectedBookId with your entities array like:

```
export const getSelected = createSelector(
  getEntities,
  getSelectedId,
  (entities , selectedId) => entities.find(entities => entities.id === selectedId)
);
```

index.ts

```
export const getSelectedBook = createSelector(getBookState, fromBook.getSelected);
```

**Finally** to get the book object you need to call your selector

```
this.book$ = this.store.select(fromRoot.getSelectedBook);
```

Comment: Ahh I see, I didn't realise I needed to store the book I wanted to retrieve inside the store first, this does make the example code make sense, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: So lets say in my component, I wanted to watch two different books via an observable, how would I do that? I would expect getSelected could take a book ID, I could then do fromRoot.getSelectedBook(BookID), but with this method I am limited to only one book?

Comment: And if you add an array to the state like selectedBookId[].

Comment: What and then in the component do getSelectedBook[id] to map the required book ID into the observable?

Comment: if I call a selector such as "this.book$ = this.store.select(fromRoot.getSelectedBook);" then extend this with something like 
```const bookExtensiond$ = book$
                 // Only fire subscription when object has someValue
                .filter(x => !!x.someValue)
                .subscription(...)```

However then when state is reset these observables are then broken with an error such as `Cannot read property 'someValue' of undefined`. Any ideas?